# Scale object equally by fixed dimension

Tags: mesh

What is the easiest way to scale this object equally from its edges outside and inside?

Basically I would like to make a slightly larger version of it so the original fits inside it like a mold with a 1mm space all around.

I can scale it with the normal scale tool but the resulting space between them is not 1mm all around because it scales proportionally.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Shrink/fatten)

[image]

Comment: That works. Thank you.